extracting json data and store into a csv file
i am performing some test cases on a PETSTORE API and the API link is https://petstore.swagger.io
now i want extract the some of json data. to do that i have used json extractor postprocessor and extracted. now i want to store the extracted response to the csv file and use the csv file in further steps. i want store these data only using beanshell.
the extracted looks like this : 
i have also tried some beanshell scripting but it is storing the first response. i want to store all the responses in a csv at once.
the beanshell scripting image is : 
json extractor expression is : $..[*].[?(@.name == 'doggie')].id
thanks in advance for the help....!!
i want store the extracted data into a csv file using beanshell
after using the given response and i tried and it is storing the values in null.


No image of code nor data please; copy paste the text into blocks of code in the question

Using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern, since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting.
If you want to extract all matches, one on new line, you could do something like:
1.upto(vars.get('PET_ID_matchNr') as int, {
    new File('somefile.csv') << vars.get('PET_ID_' + it) << System.getProperty('line.separator')
})

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?

it is storing the null values into the csv

show me your JSON Extractor configuration

path expression: $..[*].[?(@.name == 'doggie')].id    match number: -1

what is the variable name?

variable name: PET_ID
